# Does assigning to a function overwrite the function or create an implicit global?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-function-declaration

In JavaScript we can declare a function and then assign to it, as follows:

```
function spam() { return "spam 'n eggs"; }
spam = spam();
spam(); // TypeError: spam is not a function.
```

Does this code change the value of a global variable called *spam*, or create an implicit global variable that shadows the function *spam*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't overwrite the function, but it does assign a string to that variable. The function defined on the first line returns a string, and because the second line sets `spam` equal to the return value (since the function is called (notice the parentheses)) spam then is a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).

Try this in the browser console: `window.spam`. After the first line, it should reveal that function. Then after the second line it should show that string.

```js
function spam() {
  return "spam 'n eggs";
}
console.log('typeof spam: ',typeof spam, 'typeof window.spam: ',typeof window.spam);
spam = spam(); //spam is assigned a string
console.log('typeof spam: ',typeof spam, 'typeof window.spam: ',typeof window.spam);
spam(); // TypeError: spam is not a function.
```

if we moved that code inside a function, the [*var*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword could be used for local scope:

```js
function assignSpam() {
        var spam = function() { return "spam 'n eggs"; }
        console.log('typeof spam after initial assignment: ',typeof spam);
        spam = spam(); //spam is assigned a string
        console.log('typeof spam after assigning to spam(): ',typeof spam);
        spam(); // TypeError: spam is not a function.
    }
    assignSpam();
    spam; //undefined
```

Results should be similar in server-side javascript (e.g. NodeJS).

Comment: This wasn't quite what I meant by overwrite (see edit) but answers my question nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this code overwrite the function held by a global variable called spam,

No. The initial value assigned to *spam* is a reference to the function. Assigning a new value doesn't alter the function, it just assigns a new value to *spam*.

E.g.

```js
function spam(){return 'I am spam';}

var b = spam;

spam = spam();

console.log(spam) // 'I am spam'

console.log(b);   // Original "spam" function

console.log(b()); // 'I am spam'
```

> or create an implicit global variable that shadows the function spam?

It just assigns a new value to *spam*. The original function object still exists, though if there are no other references to it, it is available for garbage collection.